# How do I get coordinates from commandline prompt with node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line

How do I get the coordinates from the commandline prompt with node.js?
How long is the commandlineprompt How height is the commandline pompt.

Kind regards

Severin

Comment: Node.js doesn’t have APIs for that natively. You might want to check the “blessed” library on npm for that

Comment: I looked into the libary and it doesnt become clear to me, how they create a box where to write a message in.

Comment: process.stdout.getWindowSize()